# NavigationBar Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I got here such an error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

What is wrong with my code? I try to add image to navcontroller , I have here image as you can see.

```
func addNavBarImage() {
    let nc = navigationController!
    let image = UIImage(named: "2.png")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    let bwidth = nc.navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let bheight = nc.navigationBar.frame.size.height

    let bannerx = bwidth/2 - (image?.size.width)!/2
    let bannery = bheight/2 - (image?.size.height)!/2

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerx, y: bannery, width: bwidth, height: bheight)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error message when you don´t have a legit image added to your `let image = UIImage(named: "2000")`. It is `nil`. Your code crashes on `let bannerx = bwidth/2 - (image?.size.width)!/2`. Make sure you have the right image before you continue your execution after that row.

Replace:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "2.png")
```

With:

```
guard let image = UIImage(named: "2") else { return }
```

By doing this you don´t need the to force optional use the following rows, so replace the below rows for `bannerx` and `bannery` with yours:

```
let bannerx = bwidth/2 - (image.size.width)/2
let bannery = bheight/2 - (image.size.height)/2
```